# Web application for browsing source code repositories

Tags: git

I am using git repository and i was a web based tool for code browsing a freeware so that i can access git repository branches and their code on web page. I dont want github tool. just a separate free ware tool which can be configured to use git repo code.

Answer (score 0):

you might look at [goblet](http://git.kaarsemaker.net/goblet/). Looks as simple as it gets.